# Testing POST ActionDispatch::Http::Parameters::ParseError: 765

Tags: rspec, ruby-on-rails-5.1

It says there's an unexpected token in my params.

`"ActionDispatch::Http::Parameters::ParseError: 765: unexpected token at 'conversation_identifier[participant_list][]=2&conversation_identifier[participant_list][]=1"`

A version of the test with magic numbers for clarity:

```
let(:headers) do
  { 'HTTP_CURRENT_USER_ID' => 2,
    'Content-Type'         => 'application/json' }
end
let(:params) { { conversation_identifier: { participant_list: [1, 2] } }

it 'is getting testy' do
  post resource_url, params: params, headers: headers
  assert_equal 201, response.status
end
```

Now here's what's weird. It has no trouble parsing those params if I give it no headers.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Removing the `'Content-Type' => 'application/json'` solved the problem.

Finally remembered that ActionDispatch uses the headers to know how to parse the params. `'Content-Type' => 'application/json'` is a standard piece of boilerplate that's ok to throw around with `GET` requests and query params but not with `POST` when used this way.

Comment: Thank you for posting this - I felt like I was taking crazy pills.  You saved me 

Comment: This is not the correct answer. Instead of removing the `Content-Type` you should post a json instead a ruby hash in your request spec

Comment: @DenniJensen According to the docs you're right https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/request-specs/request-spec#providing-json-data. `params.to_json` it seems. Going to verify when I get a moment and update the answer.

Answer (score 8):

In case you still want `'Content-Type' => 'application/json'`:
You should pass params to `raw_post` and call `#to_json` on the params that you pass.

Like:

```
    let(:raw_post) { params.to_json }
```